# jquery window.location.assign() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sending form data via jquery and cannot get the window.location.assign() to fire off. I am getting a successful submission. I've also tried window.location.href =

```html
<form>
   <div>
      <a id="submitDesk" type="button" class="btn submitDesk">Submit Request</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $( "#submitDesk" ).click(function() {
            var firstname = document.querySelector('#firstname').value;
            var lastname = document.querySelector('#lastname').value;
            var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://foo.com/desk.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'firstname='+ firstname + '&lastname='+ lastname+ '&email=' + email + '&location='+ location,
                success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   window.location.assign('/thank-you/'); 
                }
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: `window.location.assign()` works fine. Are you sure your issue is that the AJAX request is failing, hence `success` is not being called at all?

Comment: What's the error? Do you need to wrap this in `(document).ready` function?

Comment: @Rowland you can clearly see the OP has document.ready in their code...

Comment: you forgot a `'` before `&email=` causing an error

Comment: edited* I am getting successful form submissions. Sorrym the data was edited wrong for SO

Comment: Succesful submission: do you mean the data is logged in the console?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the data to log in the console, but the response headers do show success. Also, the form shows in the application the desk.php is sending it to.

Comment: well, console.log any string, if that doesn't log then the problem is that the success function isn't called at all.

Comment: @yezzz, that seems to be the problem. nothing is logging in the console.

Comment: As suspected.. so you need to figure out what happens. You can pass 3 params to your succes function, the 2nd one being textstatus. Might give some clues. Also look at the network tab and check your source. If external ensure xss is possible or use jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below.  data parameter string was not proper, String was getting break, SO i have added " ' " to make it a proper string.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://foo.com/desk.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'firstname='+ firstname + '&lastname='+ lastname+ '&email='+ email+ '&location='+ location,
                success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   window.location.assign('http://foo.com/thank-you/'); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: What exactly have you changed? Please describe the error and how your code fixes it. The whole point of this site is to educate. Simply dumping code in an answer helps no one in the long term

Comment: Now updated,  Thanks for the suggestion we will keep i for later answers.

Comment: No problem. Just FYI the OP has updated their question to say that was just a typo and this is not an issue. I'd suggest deleting the answer as it's now irrelevant,

Comment: agree , so deleted , here i go.

Comment: Read comments above. I formated this data string incorrectly when posting to SO. My form submissions are success, the page is simply not redirecting.

Comment: Try passing full url and not relative url and the update us.

Comment: @amitwadhwani, used the full URL, but no redirect.

Comment: Try hitting your url in browser and check if its loading or you have any issue there.

Answer (score 0):

The backend file was sending incorrect responses causing there to always be an error even though the form was a success.